# Deprecated criteria в Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Компилятор ругается на меня из-за вот этой строки:

```
session.createCriteria(Bus.class).list();
```

В исходниках вижу это:

```
/** @deprecated */
@Deprecated
Criteria createCriteria(Class var1);

/** @deprecated */
@Deprecated
Criteria createCriteria(Class var1, String var2);

/** @deprecated */
@Deprecated
Criteria createCriteria(String var1);

/** @deprecated */
@Deprecated
Criteria createCriteria(String var1, String var2);
```

А на что заменить надо - не понятно. Нет никаких ссылок...

Comment: Если коротко - Jpa. Я пример кидать не буду, т.к. уверен что у меня запросы кривые и неправильно составлены. Ибо сам еще плохо в этом разобрался

Comment: Лучшие кривые примеры, чем посылать на три буквы (Jpa). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут все очень просто. То, что вас послали в сторону JPA - это ничего страшного :) на самом деле, это верное направление. Это API помечено deprecated потому, что оно Hibernate-specific, и его предлагают вам перевести на чистый JPA (чтобы в любой момент у вас была возможность заменить ваш ORM в лице Hibernate на любой другой или же на нативную реализацию). Вот [здесь](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#appendix-legacy-criteria) нашел описание данного факта.